# Where are the Apache and PHP log files?

Tags: apache2, php, log

I've installed Apache, PHP, and MySQL on Ubuntu 10.10 desktop edition, and it's working fine.
Except I have no clue where to look for Apache or PHP log files.

Answer (score 424, accepted):

By default, `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

This can be configured in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.

Comment: Yep. got it. it was a bit different on windows.

Comment: Apache logs can be rotated, so you might want to check all  `error.log.*` files

Comment: @misterben can you help me find enable the same error log for centOS 7? any idea?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269090/2799 has info for other distros

Comment: what if apache is not installed, just php?

Answer (score 78):

Check these settings in `php.ini`:

1. `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT` (as recommended for development in php.ini)
2. `error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log`
3. Then create log file manually

   ```
   touch /var/log/php_errors.log
   chown www-data: /var/log/php_errors.log
   chmod +rw /var/log/php_errors.log
   ```
4. And finally

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Now you can view PHP errors by this way

```
tail /var/log/php_errors.log
```

This is an agreeable solution to this issue for me.

Comment: would also need a step to restart the apache for settings to take effect

Comment: Keep it tight: `chmod 640 /var/log/php_errors.log`

Answer (score 30):

You can also define a specific error log file for each VirtualHost in Apache. If you have any VirtualHost defined in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and enabled in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` (enable with `sudo a2ensite [your-virtualhost-definition-file]`), you can change the error log by adding the following line inside your VirtualHost config:

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/[your-vhost]-error.log
```

That might be useful if you have a lot of vhosts and want to split where they report the errors.

Also, you can watch your error log live by issuing the following command (adapt to your own log file if different from the default):

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

This is particularly useful when doing live debugging.

Comment: It works! If I comment out `error_log = syslog` in php.ini

Answer (score 2):

If Apache was setup with Webmin/Virtualmin there is a separate folder for each VirtualHost.

It is

`~/logs`

folder for each VirtualHost user.

These are two files:

`~/logs/access_log`

and

`~/logs/error_log`

So they are

`/home/onedomain/logs/access_log`

`/home/onedomain/logs/error_log`

`/home/anotherdomain/logs/access_log`

`/home/anotherdomain/logs/error_log`

`...`

etc.

To view log files for each particular domain login as VirtualHost owner user of that hostname and run

`tail -f ~/logs/error_log`

Answer (score 1):

If you use a bitnami distribution, it is at:

```
tail /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log
```

Bitnami distributions have their own directory structure. I had to find what it was for my server, and this is where it resides by default for bitnami. I would assume lots of people are looking for the same thing when using a bitnami distribution.

For more info see here: https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/infrastructure/lamp/troubleshooting/debug-errors-apache/