# PHP codes of Unix in Ubuntu

Tags: php, hosting

I am using windows7 . and *VM VirtualBox* for *Ubuntu 12.04*.

I have one PHP project which is written in Unix. But now I have to host it through Ubuntu 12.04. I have already imported that project into Ubuntu server and I am able to access other php pages of Ubuntu from windows browser using IP.

Now the problem is - I am not able to access that particular project. When I try to access it shows a blank page. I am not getting any error messages(display error is enabled) for that.

Please help me.. at-least give me some hint.

Comment: What do you mean by 'written in Unix'?

Comment: PHP codes which is written in Unix operating system.

Comment: It's like I'm not understanding your issue completely but PHP code doesn't change depending on operating system. Maybe the paths.

Comment: I am also confused. Because php codes does't depends on operating system. And I checked the paths also. Its not giving any output

Comment: paths are correct

Comment: Unless I look at your code now...

Comment: #avatar .. Is there any other possibilities or settings needed ? Please let me know .. i will try it.

Comment: Unless you look at the PHP log files and see if you will find anything there. http://askubuntu.com/questions/14763/where-are-the-apache-and-php-log-files

Comment: Ok. I am trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all PHP is platform independent so nothing to do with unix or windows.

Now coming back to you problem reason could be:

1. You are including some php file (that contains some error) using 'include' or 'require' statement in the file that you are trying to access.
2. Do you have some javascript written in header of PHP page? If yes, error in that javascript page can also cause a blank response.

Try to create a new simple php file having nothing more than an echo statement. And try to access it & see if the problem persists.

Comment: thank u for ur comment...
I have tried with simply writing an echo statement and i m able to access it properly.
Regarding Javascript, I have to check... I will update u soon. Thnx

Comment: I am glad that it was helpful. To debug the errors quickly you can download the WebDeveloper extension for firefox from URL:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/?src=ss

Also if the answer was helpful you can accept the answer :)

Comment: thnx its working