# My server index.php is showing a blank page

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I have managed to set up my server and upload my first php code to see if the server is working, and it is.

- PHP 7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) (NTS)
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib5.7.23, for Linux (x86_64)
- phpmyadmin 4.5.4.1deb2ubuntu2.1

I put a folder in `/var/www/html/booking`

But when I access the folder: `localhost/booking/index.php`, I only see a white page.

I have set the error from `Off` to `On` in `php.ini`

Still I can't see any errors.

So now I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Does that page have anything in it? Can you share the code that you have put in the `index.php`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP codes of Unix in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437283/php-codes-of-unix-in-ubuntu)

Comment: `<?php 
/******************************************************/
/******** SECTION 1 TO EMBED AT THE TOP OF YOUR PAGE **/
/******************************************************/
include 'common.php';

$publickey = "";
if($settingObj->getRecaptchaEnabled() == "1") {
 require_once('include/recaptchalib.php');
 $publickey = $settingObj->getRecaptchaPublicKey();
}
//$publickey = $settingObj->getRecaptchaPublicKey();`

Comment: im going crazy, it doesent wwork...

Comment: Try to put some simple code in the index.php to see if the page will load at all. Try with:
<?php
phpinfo();
?>

Comment: the page is running with php info, but wondering why it dont run the regular code :(