# Apache nolonger able to start (could not bind to address error)

Tags: server, apache2

I run a local apahe2 and PHP set up on my Ubuntu desktop to test stuff. Mainly so I can avoid uploading utter garbage when I am creating new code.

However after a particularly problematic upgrade it seems Apache is no longer running. When I try to start or restart it I get this:

> ```
>  * Restarting web server apache2
> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
> (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
> (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
> no listening sockets available, shutting down
> AH00015: Unable to open logs
> Action 'start' failed.
> The Apache error log may have more information.
>                                                                          [fail]
>  * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
> ```

I couldn't rember where the error logs might be found (it has beena  long while) but I googled it: [Where are the Apache and PHP log files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14763/where-are-the-apache-and-php-log-files)

However `/var/log/apache2/error.log` is empty

How can I figure out what is wrong and fix it?

Notes: I am aware of the whole cannot determine FQDN thing and as I am running it only for me I've never been that bothered so long as it actually worked and I could test what I had written.

Comment: How do you start apache?

Comment: The actual command I gave was `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` due to not paying attention but normally `/etc/init.d/apache2 start` which results in pretty much the same blob of text.

Comment: Does `netstat -lptu` show any program having port 80 open?

Comment: additionally, needs to be sudo: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: *slaps slef hard* of course it needs to be sudo. I said it had been a while. Yes that is the answer.